# Remove Firebase listener on activity disappear?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In iOS, it is a [good practice](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/10/best-practices-for-ios-uiviewcontroller_6.html) to remove listeners when a view controller disappears. So is it the same in Android world? Should I remove all listeners in `onPause()` of an activity

Answer (score 1):

If we're talking about good practices you shouldn't have your listeners in your `Activity` in the first place. Whenever a configuration change (e.g. screen rotation) happens your `Activity` will call `onPause`, `onStop`, `onDestroy`, `onCreate`, `onStart`, `onResume`. If your listener is in your `Activity` rebuilding the ui on configuration changes will take way longer than needed. Google's own solution for this issue is `ViewModel` in the [Architecture Components](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel) library. The listeners should be in your `ViewModel` or maybe even a `Repository` that's called from the `ViewModel`. It's all explained in more detail in the provided link.

Comment: Yes I know. Still, should I detach listeners in view model when activity disappears?

Comment: You should extend `LiveData`, start listening in the `onActive` and detach the listener in `onInactive`, expose the extended LiveData object through the `ViewModel` and observe it from the `Activity`. This way it will handle all the complicated lifecycles for you making your app more reliable and your code easier to read.